# How to wait for all Processes to end

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I've ran some two `Process` instances in parallel:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foobar():
  return x*x

def barfoo():
  return x+x

thread_fb = Process(target = foobar, args=(3,)))
thread_bf = Process(target = barfoo, args=(3,)))
thread_fb.start(); thread_bf.start()
thread_fb.wait(); thread_bf.wait()
```

It threw this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'wait'
```

**How to wait for all `multiprocessing.Process` to end?**

**What is the the equivalent when using `threading` other multi processing/threading library?**

Comment: It's `join()`, not `wait()`. That applies for both `multiprocessing.Process` and `threading.Thread`. Also, the code as pasted will fail because you're trying to pass an argument to your two functions, but neither one takes an argument. Looks like you want `def foobar(x):` and `def barfoo(x):`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Process.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join), which is essentially threading jargon for "wait":

```
thread_fb.start()
thread_bf.start()
thread_fb.join()
thread_bf.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) method to wait for it to end.

```
thread_fb.join()
thread_bf.join()
```

Also, threads and processes aren't the same, so you might want to consider name changes.